# Tabela bootstrap, no celular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu tenho uma tabela um pouco grande
usei esse código do Bootstrap.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
...
</table>
</div>
```

Mas no mobile só aparece as 3 primeiras colunas e oculta as restante.
tem como alterar para mostrar toda a tabela, ou aparecer um barra de rolagem?

Comment: A barra de rolagem deveria aparecer normalmente. Tente mover a tabela para verificar as outras colunas.

Comment: Realmente a barra não aparece mas se mover a tabela, vai aparecendo as outras colunas :), valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade para a barra de rolagem é overflow.

```
table{
  overflow: scroll;   /* Sempre aparece a barra de rolagem */
  overflow: auto;     /* Automaticamente verifica se precisa da barra */
}
```

Mas como você comentou que é mobile eu indicaria esse artigo: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Em um desenho mobile responsivo o usuário não deveria precisar fazer zoom ou scroll horizontal.